# Error: Cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '1'

Tags: c++

I have a project to write a code that performs mathematical operations on matrices. The user inputs a matrix in the form of a string and then inputs an operator, if it's + or - or * or / then the user must enter another matrix... 
So I wanted to make a function that performs each operation and I started with ADD function, but I get an error when I call it in the main.
Example of input matrix: [3 4 9;2 5 8;1 2 50]
Note: No extra spaces or semicolons should be printed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
string ADD (float matrix1,float matrix2,int arraySize);
int main()
{
  string s1; //first matrix
  char op; //operator
  string s2;//second matrix
  int y; //for power operation
  int n = 0; //number of rows of first matrix
  int m = 0; //number of columns of first matrix
  int o = 0; //number of rows of second matrix
  int p = 0;//number of columns of second matrix

  getline(cin, s1);

  for (int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++)
  {

  if (s1[i] == ';') n++;

  }
  for (int j = 0; j < s1.size(); j++)
  {
      if (s1[j] == ' ') m++;
  }
 n = n+1;
 m = (m/n)+1;

  s1.erase(0, 1); //to remove  first bracket

  for (int z = 0; z < s1.size(); z++) //to replace characters with a space
  {
       if (s1[z] == ';' || s1[z] == ']') s1[z] = ' ';
  }
    string token1;
    float matrix1 [n*m];
    for (int x = 0; x < n*m; x++)
   {
    token1 = s1.substr(0, s1.find(" "));
    float v = atof(token1.c_str());
    matrix1 [x] = v;
    s1.erase(0, s1.find(" ")+1);
   }
   cout <<"Please Enter An Operator From The Following List: '+ - * ^ T D I /'" <<endl;
   cin >> op;
   if (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')
   {
       cin.ignore(); getline (cin,s2);
   }
   else if (op == '^') cin >> y;


   for (int f = 0; f < s2.size(); f++)
  {

  if (s2[f] == ';') o++;

  }
  for (int q = 0; q < s2.size(); q++)
  {
      if (s2[q] == ' ') p++;
  }
 o = o+1;
 p = (p/o)+1;

  s2.erase(0, 1); //to remove  first bracket

  for (int e = 0; e < s2.size(); e++) //to replace characters with a space
  {
       if (s2[e] == ';' || s2[e] == ']') s2[e] = ' ';
  }
    string token2;
    float matrix2 [o*p];
    float h;
    for (int c = 0; c <o*p; c++)
   {
    token2 = s2.substr(0, s2.find(" "));
    h = atof(token2.c_str());
    matrix2 [c] = h;
    s2.erase(0, s2.find(" ")+1);
   }
 if ( n == o && m == p && op == '+')
 {
     ADD(matrix1,matrix2,m*n) //Where I got the error Cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' for argument '1'

 }
return 0;
}
 string ADD (float matrix1[],float matrix2[],int arraySize)
{
     string str;
     for (int u = 0; u < arraySize; u++)
     {
     float matrix3[arraySize];
     matrix3[u] = matrix1[u] + matrix2[u];

     ostringstream ss;
     ss << matrix3;
     str = ss.str();
     return str;
     }
    cout <<str;
}
```

Comment: Change the declaration of `ADD` to match the definition. `string ADD (float matrix1[],float matrix2[],int arraySize)`

Comment: Warning, in C++ you aren't allowed to write `float matrix1 [n*m];` unless `n*m` is a constant (which in your code, it isn't).  You may find that the g++ compiler will let you use this feature from C, known as a variable-length array, in C++.  But others will not.  Much more portable to use dynamic allocation, for example `auto matrix1 = std::make_unique<float[]>(n*m);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forward declaration doesn't match your function definition:

```
string ADD (float matrix1,float matrix2,int arraySize);
```

and

```
string ADD (float matrix1[],float matrix2[],int arraySize)
{
...
}
```

Simply change your forward declaration to match the definition.

Comment: It worked but when I tried to print out the answer it showed a hexadecimal value not the actual summation, what should I do?

Comment: @OlaMMuhammad Please ask a separate question because your issue is not related to what was originally asked. In other words, each question should be about a specific issue, not your entire code.